# How to hide Grommet SideSplit component

Tags: css, reactjs, grommet

I have a React/redux app using the grommet ux framework.  The basic structure is:

```
    <App className="gol">
      <Article>
        <GLHeader />
          <SideSplit active={props.nav} onResponsive={checkMobile} >
             <GLNav />
             <GLBoard />
          </SideSplit>
        <Footer colorIndex="neutral-1-a" justify="center">&copy;&nbsp;2016 </Footer>
      </Article>
    </App>
```

I would like the `<GLNav />` component to be hidden unless a Settings icon is clicked, allowing the `<GLBoard />` component to fill the screen.  I have a redux state variable connected to the icon to toggle the `active` prop and also toggle a CSS class on the `<GLNav />` component.  The CSS sets the width to 0 so that the NAV component slides in and out:

```
.hide{
  width: 0 !important;
  transition: width .3s ease-out;
}
.show{
  transition: width .3s ease-out;
}
```

All of this works perfectly in Chrome.  However in Safari when the SideSplit component is in non-mobile mode (screen width greater than 750px) - even when the `active` prop is false, and the CSS class `.hide` is applied - the `<GLNav />` component has a width value.  If I change the width to less than 750px, grommet applies a `hidden` class, and that will hide the `<GLNav />` as desired.

Here is the `<GLNav />` class:

```
const GLNav = props => {
    return(
      <SideBar colorIndex="neutral-1-a" className={props.nav}>
        <Header pad="medium" justify="between">
          <Title>
            Settings
          </Title>
          <Button icon={<Close />} onClick={() => props.actions.toggleNav()} />
        </Header>
     </SideBar>
  )
}
```

Comment: Note: I also tried only rendering the `<GLNav>` component when the Settings button is clicked...while it works as expected, it doesn't apply the CSS transition in that case.

Comment: try adding `max-width: 0;`

Comment: that did it - thanks for the tip!

Comment: Glad everything is good, I will write this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying my comment to answer as it worked.

Lets' force `.hide` class maximum width to 0

```
.hide{
  width: 0 !important; /* may be you don't need !important anymore */
  max-width: 0;
  transition: width .3s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this solution works, I believe there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do, without the need for manipulating css directly.

Have you seen the Animate utility in Grommet?

https://grommet.github.io/docs/animate/examples/#1

It allows you to use a pure react approach to hide elements without needing to rely on the css to hide elements (it uses `react-addons-transition-group` behind the scenes).

In your example I would do something like this:

```
export default MyComponent extends Component {
  state = { navActive: false }

  render () {
    const { navActive } = this.state;

    let navNode;
    if (navActive) {
      navNode = (
        <Animate leave={{"animation": "slide-left", "duration": 1000}}
          visible={true}>
          <GLNav />
        </Animate>
      );
    }

    <App className="gol">
      <Article>
        <GLHeader />
          <SideSplit active={props.nav} onResponsive={checkMobile} >
             {navNode}
             <GLBoard />
          </SideSplit>
        <Footer colorIndex="neutral-1-a" justify="center">&copy;&nbsp;2016 </Footer>
      </Article>
    </App>

  }
}
```

Comment: I initially tried using the Animate component, but it seems like it allocates the width for the div all at once, then animates the component into the div.  It's kind of a disjointed user experience.